# How could I use a scoped service, later in the startup?

Tags: asp.net-core, service, startup

In ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services), I added a scoped service which I want to use later to get a value for Add authentication service.

```
services.AddScoped<IService1, Service1>();

// Add other services

 services.AddAuthentication(
 // need to use the Service1 to get a value 
)
```

Comment: An obvious solution would be to manually create (and dispose) a `Service1`.

Answer (score 0):

```
var yourService = services.BuildServiceProvider().GetRequiredService<IService1>();
```

More details about this matter can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56042989/what-are-the-costs-and-possible-side-effects-of-calling-buildserviceprovider-i/56058498#56058498) and [here](https://andrewlock.net/access-services-inside-options-and-startup-using-configureoptions/).

Credit also to Kirk Larkin and L.F. from the comments.

Comment: Close, but you'd better set up a Scope with a `using(){}`

Comment: It's generally a bad idea to use `BuildServiceProvider` in `ConfigureServices` like this. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56042989/what-are-the-costs-and-possible-side-effects-of-calling-buildserviceprovider-i/56058498#56058498).

Comment: @KirkLarkin Can you post a link to that question in order to delete my answer?

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.