# How to resolve service by service type using ServiceLocator?

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, ioc-container

I was resolving service using like this `ServiceProvider.GetService<T>()`. But then i found that Resolving Scoped Serivices was getting runtime error during calling the method `ServiceProvider.GetService<T>()` Saying service not found in root provider. Then i found to resolve creating scope like this,

```
using (var scope = _serviceProvider.CreateScope())
{
   return scope.ServiceProvider.GetService<T>();
}
```

I want to create a generic function. But the problem is i don't know when to use service provider scope and when not to use service provider as i don't know the service lifetime type(Scoped/Singleton).
How can i create this generic function that will resolve the service without knowing the lifetime or resolving the lifetime issue?

Answer (score 0):

You should not be doing this *unless there is a reason* for not injecting the services as is meant to. You can take a look here 
(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-3.1)

Also, if you are building the service provider before the ConfigureServices(..) ends could result in very subtle bugs very hard to track. Here is more in-depth information about that [What are the costs and possible side effects of calling BuildServiceProvider() in ConfigureServices()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56042989/what-are-the-costs-and-possible-side-effects-of-calling-buildserviceprovider-i)

Being said all these things, you should define the lifetime of the service in the ConfigureService(..) method on the Startup.cs with something like this

```
services.AddSingleton<ISingletonService, SingletonService>();
services.AddScoped<IScopedService, ScopedService>();
```

And when you call this logic

```
using (var scope = _serviceProvider.CreateScope())
{
   return scope.ServiceProvider.GetService<T>();
}
```

The ServiceProvider itself handles the service lifetime with the code on the ConfigureServices.

Hope it helps you!