# How to get to DI container in AddControllers

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, asp.net-core-webapi

I would like to register in- and outputformatters in DI, however I don't know how to get to the DI container in the `AddControllers` method:

```cs
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services
    .AddTransient<TexInputFormatter, MyInputFormatter>()
    .AddTransient<TextOutputFormatter, MyOutputFormatter>()
    .AddControllers(c =>
    {
        c.InputFormatters.Clear();
        c.OutputFormatters.Clear();
        
        // How do I get to the DI container here?
        c.InputFormatters.Add(???.GetRequiredService<TextInputFormatter>());
        c.OutputFormatters.Add(???.GetRequiredService<TextOutputFormatter>());
    });

var app = builder.Build();
app.Run();
```

I did come up with one 'workaround' by declaring `app` earlier and the capturing it, but I don't like that solution:

```cs
WebApplication? app = null;  // Declare app here
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services
    .AddTransient<TexInputFormatter, MyInputFormatter>()
    .AddTransient<TextOutputFormatter, MyOutputFormatter>()
    .AddControllers(c =>
    {
        c.InputFormatters.Clear();
        c.OutputFormatters.Clear();
        
        // Use app.Services here
        c.InputFormatters.Add(app!.Services.GetRequiredService<TextInputFormatter>());
        c.OutputFormatters.Add(app!.Services.GetRequiredService<TextOutputFormatter>());
    });

app = builder.Build();
app.Run();
```

Edit: Ofcourse I could do:

```cs
c.InputFormatters.Add(new MyInputFormatter());
c.OutputFormatters.Add(new MyOutputFormatter());
```

However, both formatters have a bunch of other dependencies and constructor arguments I want DI to resolve for me.

How would I go about this?

Comment: @PeterCsala That won't work because a) the servicecollection isn't built yet and b) the builder.Services doesn't have a GetRequiredService method.

Comment: How about this? https://andrewlock.net/accessing-services-when-configuring-mvcoptions-in-asp-net-core/

Comment: from Microsoft [documents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/advanced/custom-formatters?view=aspnetcore-6.0#specify-supported-media-types-and-encodings), it is clearly given that you can't use constructor DI but you can use context info and resolve the dependency whenever needed. there is also [sample](https://github.com/dotnet/AspNetCore.Docs/blob/main/aspnetcore/web-api/advanced/custom-formatters/samples/6.x/CustomFormattersSample/Formatters/VcardInputFormatter.cs) available on how to do it.

Comment: @CodingMytra Where is 't "clearly given" that I can't use constructor DI? What prevents me to make a `MyOutputFormatter(IOptions<Myoptions> options, ILogger<...> logger, ISomething something)`? As a matter of fact, it works just fine as long as I can get to the DI container. Yes, I can use the context but that would mean accessing the DI container on every input/output where my formatters are perfectly fine as a Singleton (if so desired). I would like to perform some (a little) work in the constructor, but prefer to do it just once.

Comment: Using the context is almost certainly the best idea. If you are afraid of performance issues, then save those things you extract from the service provider in static variables.

Comment: @DavidG Yeah, I guess so. I'll go for the context (for now )

Comment: "A formatter class can not use constructor injection for its dependencies". this line is written in the document link I shared.

Comment: @DavidG If you post your comment as an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 0):

You need a IServiceProvider to get something from your ServiceContainer.
To do that you need to build it.

You could use something like that

```
builder.Services.BuildServiceProvider();
```

However i read somewhere that this is not the right way to do it (You should not build the provider twice).

Related:
For services you could do:

```
builder.Services.AddSingletion<IFoo, MyService>(serviceProvider => serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<IFoo2>();...);
```

Comment: Yes, that's also not a preferred option. Maybe it works but it's not recommended.

Comment: See [this q&a](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56042989/what-are-the-costs-and-possible-side-effects-of-calling-buildserviceprovider-i/56058498#56058498) on why building extra service providers is typically a bad idea.

Comment: @Steven Thanks, that was exactly what i was refering to

Answer (score -1):

You don't need DI for adding input or output formatters.
just adding new instance should be fine.

check this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/advanced/custom-formatters?view=aspnetcore-6.0) and [this one](https://www.infoworld.com/article/3356437/how-to-use-output-formatters-in-aspnet-core.html) for more details:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services
    .AddControllers(c =>
    {
        c.InputFormatters.Clear();
        c.OutputFormatters.Clear();
        
        // How do I get to the DI container here?
        c.InputFormatters.Add(new MyInputFormatter());
        c.OutputFormatters.Add(new MyOutputFormatter());
    });

var app = builder.Build();
app.Run();
```

Comment: I know, but my in- and outputformatters each have a bunch of constructor arguments that I would also like DI to resolve for me. I'll add that to my question. (And just so we're clear, the downvote isn't mine...)

Comment: that's fine, it was not clear from your que that you needed additional dependencies.