# ServiceCollection Extension method with a dependency as parameter?

Tags: c#, .net-core, dependency-injection

i'm writing a library with a pre-configured `GraphServiceClient` and i've created an extension method to register it via dependency injection:

```cs
internal static IServiceCollection AddGraphClient(this IServiceCollection services, 
    IConfiguration proxyConfig, 
    IConfiguration credentialConfig)
{
    services.Configure<GraphAuthProxySettings>(proxyConfig);
    services.Configure<GraphAuthCredentialSettings>(credentialConfig);
    services.AddSingleton<IGraphAuthService, GraphAuthService>();
    services.AddSingleton<IIdentityLogger, GraphAuthIdentityLogger>();
    services.AddSingleton<IMsalHttpClientFactory, GraphAuthHttpClientFactory>();
    services.AddTransient<DelegatingHandler, GraphAuthTokenHandler>();
    services.AddSingleton(sp =>
    {
        var handlers = GraphClientFactory.CreateDefaultHandlers();
        handlers.Add(sp.GetRequiredService<GraphAuthTokenHandler>());
        handlers.Add(sp.GetRequiredService<HttpLoggingHandler>()); // problematic line
        var httpClient = GraphClientFactory.Create(handlers);
        return new GraphServiceClient(httpClient);
    });
    return services;
}
```

The problem is that `HttpLoggingHandler` isn't part of the library and i wanna be able to add the last handler as a parameter.

What kinda worked is adding a `Func` and call `services.BuildServiceProvider()`

```cs
internal static IServiceCollection AddGraphClient<TService>(this IServiceCollection services, 
    IConfiguration proxyConfig, 
    IConfiguration credentialConfig, 
    Func<IServiceProvider, TService> factory) where TService : DelegatingHandler
{
    TService finalHandler = factory(services.BuildServiceProvider());
    // ...
    services.AddSingleton(sp =>
    {
        var handlers = GraphClientFactory.CreateDefaultHandlers();
        handlers.Add(sp.GetRequiredService<GraphAuthTokenHandler>());
        handlers.Add(finalHandler);
        var httpClient = GraphClientFactory.Create(handlers);
        return new GraphServiceClient(httpClient);
    });
    return services;
}
```

But that's bad and causes issues with the service life time: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56058498/1018144

I could add the `DelegatingHandler` as regular parameter but that would mean i have to instantiate it manually and it would also cause issues with the service lifetime:

```cs
internal static IServiceCollection AddGraphClient(this IServiceCollection services, 
    IConfiguration proxyConfig, 
    IConfiguration credentialConfig, 
    DelegatingHandler finalHandler)
{
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All right, with the help of another user in a different community, we came up with the following solution, which uses method parameters instead of the generic type

```cs
internal static IServiceCollection AddGraphClient(this IServiceCollection services,
    IConfiguration proxyConfig,
    IConfiguration credentialConfig,
    Func<IServiceProvider, DelegatingHandler> customHandlerFactory)
{
    // ...
    services.AddSingleton(sp =>
    {
        var handlers = GraphClientFactory.CreateDefaultHandlers();
        handlers.Add(customHandlerFactory(sp));
        var httpClient = GraphClientFactory.Create(handlers);
        return new GraphServiceClient(httpClient);
    });
    return services;
}
```

```cs
builder.Services.AddGraphClient(
    builder.Configuration.GetSection("Proxy"),
    builder.Configuration.GetSection("GraphCredentials"),
    sp => sp.GetRequiredService<HttpLoggingHandler>()
);
```

And if you wanna implement it with a list instead of a single `DelegatingHandler`:

```cs
internal static IServiceCollection AddGraphClient(this IServiceCollection services,
    IConfiguration proxyConfig,
    IConfiguration credentialConfig,
    Func<IServiceProvider, IEnumerable<DelegatingHandler>> customHandlerFactory)
{
    // ...
    services.AddSingleton(sp =>
    {
        var handlers = GraphClientFactory.CreateDefaultHandlers();
        var customHandlers = customHandlerFactory(sp);
        foreach (var handler in customHandlers)
        {
            handlers.Add(handler);
        }
        var httpClient = GraphClientFactory.Create(handlers);
        return new GraphServiceClient(httpClient);
    });
    return services;
}
```

```cs
builder.Services.AddGraphClient(
    builder.Configuration.GetSection("Proxy"),
    builder.Configuration.GetSection("GraphCredentials"),
    sp => new DelegatingHandler[]
        {
            sp.GetRequiredService<WhatEverHandler>(),
            sp.GetRequiredService<HttpLoggingHandler>(),
        }
);
```